# PHP- difference between instantiating a class and returning the instantiation

Tags: php, class, oop

The normal class declaration and instantiation:

```
class Foo {
    // properties
    // methods 
}

new Foo();
```

The class declaration and instantiation with return:

```
class FooBar {
    // properties
    // methods 
}

return new FooBar();
```

What is the difference between these two in PHP in terms of using the classes?

Comment: the fact that the first basically does nothing (unless you're doing crazy stuff in the constructor), the 2nd returns the instance from a method/function.. but still does nothing until what was returned is used in some way. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @OliverO'Neill Not exactly. Let's say I have normal methods and properties inside both. And I instantiate them like so above. I new up the first one in a variable and use it to call the methods as usual. Now, if I return the class like FooBar, how do I use that to run the methods inside?

Comment: You don't return class, you return __instance of class__.

Comment: I really HIGHLY super recommend that you look up how to do objects in PHP. It's really quite easy, when you call `new` you allocate that to a variable. then you call methods on that variable (which is the instace of that class that you just created). 

That's really the simplest i can explain. try reading more examples of how objects are used, and play around with it. And then ask more certain questions.

Comment: @OliverO'Neill, Thanks for your explanation. I actually know how objects in PHP works. Was just wondering what's the purpose of returning a class instance like that. The answer below actually clarified. I was trying to understand that, the constructor being executed through this simple return. You touched on that in your first comment by the way. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just return new FooBar() it will just execute its __construct method if it has.
But you can call methods without assigning objects to a variable. Like this:

```
return (new FooBar())->yourMethod();
```